# Bundling JS files containing import keywords

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I am using `TypeScript` and `SystemJS` in my project. I have the following scenario:

resources.ts file:

```
import {Cache} from "../caching/cache"
...
...
```

cache.ts file:

```
import * as moment from "moment";

export class Cache<TObject, TKey> {
   ...
}
```

So, briefly, the `resources.ts` file depends on the `cache.ts` file. Both of these files are my code, but they could depend on other 3rd party tools like `momentjs` library, as you can see from the content of `cache.ts` file.

Now since I bundle my code as one JS file, I don't want the import statement in `resources.ts` to actually make any request to obtain `cache.ts`; that file is simply in the same bundle. However, for cases like `import * as moment from "moment"`, I do want it to make a request to CDNJS and obtain the moment file from there.

Is this possible? What configuration do I need to make?

Comment: what tool do you use for bundling ?

Comment: I am currently using `uglify` through `Grunt`.